# Create a wordpress admin user and only let them edit and post blog posts?

Tags: users

Is it possible to create a WordPress admin user and only let them edit and post blog posts?

Comment: Isn't this just the role of the Author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "admin user" I'm guessing you mean someone who can log into the backend. If so, yes, you can go to Users > Add New in the backend, and create a user with the "Role" dropdown set to "Author".

[image: Adding an "author" user.]

This person will be able to delete, edit, and publish posts, as well as upload files (e.g. pictures). See http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Author for more information.

If you need a user role with more limited capabilities (e.g. can only edit and publish posts, can't delete them), use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ to edit the user roles.